# Can't push back a class object because of constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, unordered-map

I have this piece code where I try to push into a vector an already constructed element from an `unordered_map`:

```
class A {
public:
    A(const std::string& a) {}
}

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, A> map {{"A", A("A")}, {"B", A("B")}};
    std::vector<A> vec;
    vec.push_back(map["A"]);
}
```

But why I'm getting errors regarding to the the vector's `push_back`:

```
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/tuple:1586:70: error: no matching function for call to 'A::A()'
         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
                                                                      ^
main.cpp:8:9: note: candidate: A::A(const string&)
         A(const std::string& a) {}
         ^
main.cpp:8:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cpp:6:7: note: candidate: constexpr A::A(const A&)
 class A {
       ^
main.cpp:6:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cpp:6:7: note: candidate: constexpr A::A(A&&)
main.cpp:6:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Comment: Note that if you don't want to create a default constructor for your type (or it's impossible), you can use `map::find()` method instead of `operator[]` - the former has the option of returning "no element found" (`map::end()`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that when using `std::unordered_map::operator[]` [(ref)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) your `mapped_type` (`A`) must be [default constructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/DefaultConstructible), the `key_type` must be [move constructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveConstructible) which is not an issue with `std::string` in your example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

class A {
public:
    A(const std::string& a) {}
    A() {} // Default constructor
};

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, A> map {{"A", A("A")}, {"B", A("B")}};
    std::vector<A> vec;
    vec.push_back(map["A"]); // Requires default constructor
    vec.push_back(map.at("A")); // Do NOT requires default constructor
}
```

Comment: Not `DefaultInsertable`. That implies that the object is directly constructed by the allocator's `construct`, which is not the case.

Comment: @T.C. Updated, the answer.

Answer (score 3):

With the question having a C++11 tag, the above answers could mention that you don't need an actual implementation of a default constructor, but that you can use the `=default` specifier to convey that is the only reason it's needed.

```
class A {
public:
    A() = default;
    A(const std::string& a) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::map::operator[]` [requires](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) the mapped type (in your case, `A`) to be [default-insertable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/DefaultInsertable), so you have to provide a default constructor, which you have not, for example:

```
class A {
public:
    A(){}
    A(const std::string& a) {}
}
```